# AngularJS - Show a form from a table row

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with `materials` and when I click I want to show a form with all the data related to the row. What is the best approach to do that?

You can see my code below

**index.html**

```
<section ng-controller="materialController as materialCtrl">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <th> Nombre </th>
        <th> Descripción </th>
        <tr ng-repeat="material in materials" ng-click="materialCtrl.openForm()">
            <td>
                {{material.name}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{material.description}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("materialController", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){        

       $http.get('material').success(function(data){
           $scope.materials = data;
       });

       this.openForm = function(){
           // Do something
       };

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you could solve this by storing the material in some scope variable and using that to determine which row has been clicked. Second, you're doing this controller thing wrong and I will show you how to fix it. You're referencing the controller directly which is probably not the best practice. I suggest you change your code to look like this

```
app.controller("materialController", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){        

       $http.get('material').success(function(data){
           $scope.materials = data;
       });
        $scope.selectedRow;

       $scope.openForm = function(material){
            $scope.selectedRow = material;
       };

}]);

   <!--reference controller directly -->
    <section ng-controller="materialController">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <th> Nombre </th>
            <th> Descripción </th>
            <!-- reference openForm from scope -->
            <tr ng-repeat="material in materials" ng-click="openForm(material)">
                <td>
                    {{material.name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{material.description}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
```

then for each material if you have some form you want to show or anything else

```
<form ng-repeat="material in materials" ng-show="selectedRow == material">
```

Also, this isn't so important but more of a best practice, you should extract your http request into a service. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea create a form for each `material`. Supose that I have 100000 `materials` and I need edit just one or two. It would be very inefficient. I want to load the data in one form

Comment: @Overflow012 well thats what you said in the question, regardless this is what you wanted. Try phrasing your question better in the future. Instead of doing an ngshow you can just bind the selectedRow to the data in the form.

Comment: Thank you! Why is it a bad practice do it this way `this.openForm = function(){...}`?

Comment: @Overflow012 because you're not using the model. With angular you want to separate the model from the view from the controller. The way you're referencing that function is directly on the object as opposed to the scope. the controller itself shouldnt really be used directly that way.